# iOS native client app for website

Tags: iphone, ios, database, drupal

I am running a site in drupal and one in Joomla. I would like to create two native iOS client apps for the users of these websites. I would like to know one basic thing. Should the apps connect straight to the sites database? or is there any other way to do that (xml or other way)?

thank you in advance.

(the sites run in mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using the provided RESTful interfaces for each platform ([drupal](https://drupal.org/project/restws) / [joomla](https://github.com/search?q=joomla%20rest&ref=cmdform)).